# Is true async (correct way to poll an async task)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is this "true async" (i.e. non-blocking and no new threads created)?

```
var asyncTask = DoSomethingAsync();
asyncTask.Start();
log.Info("Started!");
while (asyncTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
{
    log.Info("Still running ...");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
log.Info("Complete!);
```

Furthermore, is it even correct?

Comment: Usually a `DoSomethingAsync()` function will return a Task object that's already been started.

Comment: This is a very suspect morsel of code and mostly likely needs a massive rethink, what are you actually trying to achieve and why.. the answers to your questions respectively are no. and most likely no

Answer (score 0):

The asyncTask.Start() call can be removed assuming the DoSomethingAsync() method is doing some async thing. I'd remove the loop with the Task.Delay(1000) in it as it will delay for a full second even if the task is completed well before that. Minimally you could just do this:

```
var asyncTask = DoSomethingAsync();
log.Info("Started!");

await asyncTask;
log.Info("Complete!);
```

If you want to write a "Still running" log entry every second then after log.Info("Started") you could start a timer that does the logging and then stop it after the await asyncTask;:

```
try
{
    var asyncTask = DoSomethingAsync();
    log.Info("Started!");
    timerRunningLog.Start();
    await asyncTask;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do something with the exception... (e.g. log, throw)
}
finally
{
    timerRunningLog.Stop();
    log.Info("Complete!);
}
```

Here's some good info: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)